# Character to decimal conversion

Tags: python, parsing, reinventing-the-wheel, integer

This converts from character representation of integers to their decimal value:

```
def chrtodec(str):
    dec = 0
    base = ord('0')
    for chr in str:
        dec = dec * 10 + ord(chr) - base
    return dec
```

For example: "123" -> 123

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use `chr` or `str` as names because they shadow the builtin `chr` and `str` methods. If you then wanted to use `str()` you'd be out of luck because `str` is now a string instead of a function. Given that your function deals with both strings and character ordinals it is not unlikely that these could be used. `string` is a potential improvement, it can occasionally cause trouble if you're trying to use the `string` module of the same name.

You should also add comments and a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Docstrings are basically comments that are programmatically accessible so that other users can understand how to use your function.

```
def chrtodec(str):
    """Converts a string to a float using character ordinal positions."""
```

I think you have another big problem though, which is invalid input handling. Take a look at these:

```
>>> chrtodec("hello")
619663
>>> chrtodec("12.21")
11821
>>> chrtodec("523.32f")
5228374
```

Clearly there are problems here when you have characters other than numbers, so I think what you should do is raise a `ValueError` when an invalid string is passed. You already have the tools to do this figured out of course if you just check that a character's ordinal fits in the right range.

```
if not (ord('0') <= ord(chr) <= ord('9')):
    raise ValueError("Invalid character {} in string {},"
                     "only digits are parseable.".format(chr, str))
```

You could also just use `chr.isdigit()` as @Barry pointed out.

Also you could add support for negative numbers by checking at the start if the first character is `ord('-')`.

```
negative = ord(str[0]) == ord('-')
```

This evaluates the expression `str[0] == ord('-')` and sets `negative` as the boolean result. Note that to make this compatible with the error handling I suggested, you should then remove the first character from `str`. And probably update the error message and docstring too.

```
if negative:
    str = str[1:]
```

Then just return with a ternary that checks `negative`.

```
return dec if not negative else -dec
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code lacks modularization, This problem can be decomposed in:

- Find the numerical value of a char.
- Transform the chars into digits
- Multiply all this numerical values by 10 ** position and sum them.

```
def char_to_integer(char):
    return ord(char) - ord('0')
```

The second function is an excellent place for a generator expression:

```
def string_to_digits(string):
    return (char_to_integer(i) for i in string)
```

Finally:

```
def digits_to_integer(digits):
    return sum(digit * 10 ** ( len(digits) - position )
        for position, digit in enumerate(digits))
```

Comment: @Barry thanks for commenting! This is indeed slower than OP's solution but I would avoid premature opimization in this case. I find it so much more readable. This is a single expression. Look how similar this is to the mathematical definition of a positional number system. Also this uses many built-in functions `enumerate`, `reversed` and `sum` thus delegating the work to Python itself as it is idiomatic

Comment: @Barry I refactored even more, the code has also become more testable and this is much faster to write than the original solution in my opinion

Comment: @Caridorc, I agree with Barry. I don't think the code is readable in first place.

Answer (score 2):

You don't support negative numbers. But that's actually pretty easy to add, all you need to do is:

```
chrtodec = int
```

That also has the handy ability to support arbitrary base conversions too!

Comment: Seriously! I was trying to do in the native way. I think you are kidding, right?

Comment: Actually I am learning problem solving and according to me that's not a better approach.

Comment: Np, I keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

***Please*** *improve your naming!*

I've come to love the *"straight-to-the-point"* Python syntax a lot, and I embrace the delicious syntactic sugar of the language; but I keep seeing really bad naming of things among Python programmers. Maybe try this?

```
def number_as_string_to_decimal(number_as_string):
    decimal = 0
    base = ord('0')
    for character in number_as_string:
        decimal = decimal * 10 + ord(character) - base
    return decimal
```

Comment: I agree, if you're trying to be short I'd at least use `char`.

Comment: I don't think these names are better, either. The function does not convert a *character* to a *decimal*, but a *string representing an integer in decimal notation* to an *integer*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that distinction, I changed my naming suggestions accordingly.